# Mock object c++

Tags: c++, testing, mocking, tdd

I was reading about TDD and wondering is it possible to write any mock object without using extra test library like easyMock or sth like that.

For example I have code:

```
class Person
{
  int age;
  int add ( int x) { return this.age + x }
}
```

How to write mock object to test above code ?

Comment: what do you want to mock here ? I think the test is straight forward in this case and there is no mocking required at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't test a classes like that with a mock of that class. You test interfaces. In fact, your code looks like it could be a mock object to test some other code.

```
// defined in code that is being tested
class Person {
    virtual int add(int) = 0;
}
void foo(const Person& bar) {
    // use person somehow
}
```

To test the above interface, you can create a mock object. This object does not have the requirements that a real implementation might have. For example while a real implementation might require a database connection, the mock object does not.

```
class Mock: public Person {
    int add(int x) {
        // do something less complex than real implementation would
        return x;
    }
}

Mock test;
foo(test);
```

Using inheritance is not necessary if you want to test say, a template function.

```
template<class T>
void foo(T bar) {
    // Code that uses T.add()
}
```

To test interface like this, you can define mock object like this

```
class Mock {
    int add(int x) {
        // do something less complex than real implementation would
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I need to understand . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Mocking is useful when you have external resources used in your code (e.g. databases, files, etc).  To do this, you would implement those interfaces in such a way that it would "fake" the required steps so that the code you are actually testing (your business logic) can be tested without having to worry about a false-negative test due to situations in the external resources.

The code you have posted does not require mocking to test it.

Comment: Thanks. Do U know any simple example of mock object in c++ ?

Comment: I mean sth to see how it works using simple mock class

Comment: If you had a class that needed a database connection, for example, you would mock that database connection to return controlled data used in your test.  The mock would be your hard-coded implementation.  Unlike scripting or managed languages, C++ does not have the ability to do a partial mock (that is just mocking the features you are using in a given test); you must provide a basic implementation for every function in the class/interface.